# How can I see what is utilizing my localhost interface?

Tags: web-server, localhost, interface

I have a webserver that has almost 4mbps of sustained traffic on the localhost interface. How can I tell what is causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a linux system, you can perform a packet capture on your `lo` interface via something like:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo
```

Comment: and if tcpdump isn't available or allowed to be installed, you can insert an iptables rule to log all new connections on `lo`.  That will show you the uid/gid.  `iptables -I INPUT -i lo -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix="LOOPBACK_LOG: " --log-ip-options --log-level 7`  Use `iptables-save|grep LOOP` to see your rule and later delete with `-D` instead of `-I`.  This will go to syslog.